# JavaScript inside ejs code

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I need "input" a script in my .ejs file like that:

```
<% results.forEach(function(element) {
        var atuador = element.atuador;
        var status = element.status;
        if (atuador === 'QTD1LAMP'){
            if (status === 'ON'){
                $('#QTD1LAMP').bootstrapToggle('on');
            } else {
                $('#QTD2LAMP').bootstrapToggle('off');
            } 
        } else if (atuador === "QTD2LAMP"){
            if (status === "ON"){
                $('#QTD2LAMP').bootstrapToggle('on');
            } else {
                $('#QTD2LAMP').bootstrapToggle('off');
            }
        }
    })
%>
```

When i will toogle my button inside my template, for each result i will receive. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

i think you misunderstand ejs.

script inside `<% ... %>` block must be node.js script, not front-end script

if you want to embed front-end script to ejs file, just simply do like this

```
<script>
// add script front-end here
</script>
```

Comment: lets say you wanted to get the `results` the OP uses in a js file and not in a  `<script>` tag. I can't do that. If you do <%results%> in `.js`  I can't get access to the array.

Comment: Also I would like to see how you would change the OPs code using your method. If you do that I will give you an upvote. just let me know so I know you did it.